# Texworks messes up quotation marks

Tags: texworks, quoting, quotation

When I try to input double quotes `"` in Texworks, it always changes it to two single quotes `''`.

Also when I input single quotes or doubles quotes `'ab'`, it always changes them to backticks if it is at the beginning of a string `` `ab' ``.

Is this expected behavior? How can I fix this so that it does not behave this way? I am on Windows, my input is UTF-8.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I don't know texworks, but apart from `verbatim` and similar code environments you should never have `"` in latex text, the input is what you say the editor is making: `\`\`xxx''` and `\`x'`

Comment: the format menu, last entry. Set there the option to "none" or similar

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes in LaTeX are started with *two backticks* and ended with two *single ticks*, like so:

```
``Here is what I want in quotes!''
```

Using actual quotation marks will not get you what you want.